# fetch collection of inner objects nested MVC4 EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, entity-framework-6

How we can fetch collection of inner objects in a nested model.

Say model is

```
Model.MInner1.MInner2.MInner3
```

All the inner objects are List. I have only DbSet of Models and need to fetch collection of MInner3 with a condition

```
MInner3.status == 1
```

Comment: if I understand well, since MInner3 is a list, right?

var fetchList = Model.MInner1.MInner2.MInner3.where(x=>x.status == 1).toList();

Comment: MInner1 is a list?  MInner2 is a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `DbSet` property for `MInner3` defined in your `DbContext`, you could still use [`DbContext.Set<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg696521(v=VS.113).aspx). For your question:

```
// Assumming MInner3 is also the type name
var filteredSetMInner3 = context.Set<MInner3>().Where(m => m.status == 1);
```

Comment: I have one more doubt with the above model. Suppose MInner3 collection contains 2 object and 3 variable. When i make list of parent Model by loading all inner objects with "Include()" there is missing of some MInner3 items. Since there are two objects i added ".Include("MInner1.MInner2.MInner3.Object1").Include("MInner1.MInner2.MInner3.Object2")". This gives wrong result. What is the correct way to load such nested models